# Finding similar items in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table of items:

```
╔════════╦═══════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ ItemID ║ Color ║ Size  ║ Smell  ║
╠════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ Z300   ║ black ║ big   ║ stinky ║
║ Z200   ║ white ║ big   ║ stinky ║
║ Z100   ║ black ║ small ║ stinky ║
║ Z050   ║ black ║ small ║ yummy  ║
╚════════╩═══════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

Let's say I want to find items that are similar to the Z300. They can only be considered "similar" if 2/3 (color, size, smell) match it. So the Z200 and Z100 would match but the Z050 wouldn't because it only matches on 1/3. I need help writing a SQL query to produce this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is it always going to be Color,Size,Smell or will the columns be dynamic and the 2/3 matching rule also be dynamic

Comment: The columns will be static and the matching rule will be static.  In my real application I have 7 columns and I want them to match 6/7 but I simplified it in my post.

Comment: Are you sure my solution isn't easier to deal with if you have 7 different columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickie, locally tested (using Postgres, but should work on MySQL too when you remove the `public.` prefix):

```
select
    foo2.*
from
    public.foo as foo1
left join
    public.foo as foo2 on (
        foo1.Color = foo2.Color and foo1.Size  = foo2.Size  or
        foo1.Size  = foo2.Size  and foo1.Smell = foo2.Smell or
        foo1.Smell = foo2.Smell and foo1.Color = foo2.Color
    )
where
    foo1.id = 'Z300';
```

Comment: @Hamlet great minds think alike, we almost gave the exact same answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This should be close to what you need.
I added an additional row of data that is not similar to any of the other items to show what happens when there is no match.  Add a where clause to the query to limit to a single base item if desired.

```
DECLARE @Items TABLE (
    ItemId      VARCHAR(16),
    Color       VARCHAR(16),
    Size        VARCHAR(16),
    Smell       VARCHAR(16)
);
INSERT @Items 
SELECT 'Z300', 'black', 'big', 'stinky'
UNION SELECT 'Z200', 'white', 'big', 'stinky'
UNION SELECT 'Z100', 'black', 'small', 'stinky'
UNION SELECT 'Z050', 'black', 'small', 'yummy'
UNION SELECT 'Z025', 'yellow', 'medium', 'tasty'

SELECT
    Base.ItemId AS BaseItemId, 
    Base.Color AS BaseItemColor, 
    Base.Size AS BaseItemSize, 
    Base.Smell AS BaseItemSmell,
    Sim.ItemId AS SimilarItemId,
    Sim.Color AS SimilarItemColor,
    Sim.Size AS SimilarItemSize,
    Sim.Smell AS SimilarItemSmell
FROM @Items AS Base
LEFT JOIN @Items AS Sim
ON ( 
    (Base.Color = Sim.Color AND Base.Size = Sim.Size ) OR
    (Base.Color = Sim.Color AND Base.Smell = Sim.Smell ) OR
    (Base.Size = Sim.Size AND Base.Smell = Sim.Smell ) 
   ) AND Base.ItemId != Sim.ItemId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily scale this query to your requirement. For 6/7 you will have 7 `OR` conditions.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT T1.*
FROM tbl T1
   JOIN tbl T2
      ON T1.Color =T2.Color AND T1.Size = T2.Size
       OR T1.Color =T2.Color AND T1.Smell = T2.Smell
       OR T1.Size =T2.Size AND T1.Smell = T2.Smell
```

Comment: That will return any row that matches one criteria including the original row. Not what the question is asking.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, of course original row will returned but your assumption about matches one criteria is wrong.

Comment: Nope, as you are missing a bit of SQL you should have a WHERE T2.ItemID = 'Z300' otherwise all rows are returned.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Once again, original row will returned but **NOT** which matches one criteria. And adding the AND `T1.ItemID != T2.ItemID` condition to predicate will fix query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "adding up the matches" is more maintainable if you add more attributes.

```
select a.*, b.*
from mycars a
inner join mycars b
on (
    case when a.Color = b.Color  then 1 else 0 end
    case when a.Size = b.Size  then 1 else 0 end
    case when a.Smell = b.Smell  then 1 else 0 end)  > 1
  and a.ItemID > b.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be extensible without having to have a lot of additional clauses.
Only issue is that it won't find something that is an exact match.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT T1.*
FROM Items T1
   JOIN Items T2
      ON (T1.Color <> T2.Color)
       XOR NOT (T1.Size <> T2.Size)
       XOR NOT (T1.Smell <> T2.Smell)
WHERE T2.ItemID = 'Z300'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2034e/7

Comment: The OP tagged as tsql, and there is no logical `XOR` operator in t-sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer 2008 R2 or a newer version you can self-join with an unpivoted version of the table and then check the number of valid condition, like this:

```
WITH info AS (
   SELECT ItemID, property, value
   FROM (SELECT itemid, color, size, smell FROM data) p
   UNPIVOT
   (value FOR property IN (color, size, smell)) AS unpvt
)
SELECT data.itemID, info.ItemID similar
FROM   data
       INNER JOIN info on value in (color, size, smell)
GROUP BY data.itemID, info.ItemID
HAVING count(info.ItemID) = 2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/902ce/5)